# Changing camera location in script and rendering - problem with keyframes resetting the location before render

Tags: python, animation, scripting, camera, keyframes

What I do is that I change the camera location in Python API and render a new view. Here is an example:

```
import bpy
import copy
import os

#backup
camera = bpy.context.scene.camera
originalCameraLocation = copy.deepcopy(camera.location)
renderInfo = bpy.context.scene.render
originalPath = copy.deepcopy(renderInfo.filepath)

cameraStep = 0.2
stepCount = 5
#iterating and shifting the camera along X axis + render
for i in range(0,stepCount):
    camera.location[0] += cameraStep
    renderInfo.filepath = os.path.join(originalPath, str(i))
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

camera.location = originalCameraLocation
renderInfo.filepath = originalPath
```

This is working fine until I use keyframes to animate the location of the camera. No matter where I put them. This is the standard behavior in Blender, I am aware of this. Blender resets the given attribute according to the keyframes before rendering.

I would like to seamlessly integrate the animation into my logic. My goal is to get the current camera location as the initial one in my loop (affected by the animation if keyframes are present) and make the shifting relative to that. This is probably working when I simply do this, right?

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(currentFrame)
animatedLocation = camera.location
```

The issue is that the line:

```
camera.location[0] += cameraStep
```

in my code does nothing due to the position reset before rendering. Is there any way to disable this resetting or temporarily disable the whole animation just for the rest of the loop? So basically having the loop like this:

```
#this should be affected by the keyframes
currentFrameCamera = copy.deepcopy(camera.location)
for i in range(0,stepCount):
       currentFrameCamera += cameraStep
       ...disable the keyframes so the new location reaches rendering...
       camera.location = currentFrameCamera
       ...rendering...
```

I can think of inserting a new keyframe every time I change the location but I'd need to backup the possible existing ones, restoring them afterwards etc. That feels a bit hacky. Another, probably better solution would be to create a new camera or rather duplicate the existing one, removing the animation keyframes there, setting the location, setting the new camera as active, and removing it after render. I would like to discuss which solution is optimal or if there's something better to do. Thanks!

Comment: Creating a new camera is, imho, a clean and easy solution. Just be careful : if you copy the camera then delete keyframes, they will be deleted for the first camera too (because they share the same Action). You should unlink the Action from the new Camera (with something like "myNewCamera.animation_data.action = None")

Comment: Thanks @thibsert for the information about the Action. That would probably give me a lot of headaches before finding out :D. I guess I will go for the new Camera solution then.